# How do I count how many times a Div is viewed?

Tags: hitcounter

I need to count how many times a div is viewed.  Most hit counters count how many times a page is loaded but I want to count how many times a div is viewed.  There are different pages that this div is located on and I need to know how many times it is viewed in total...regardless of what page it is viewed on.  Please help!!!!  I have spent 20hrs on this and I'm a newbie in desperation.  Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Place a view counter in the div?

Comment: I've tried to place a hit counter in the div but that only displays when the page is loaded.  It's also from an external source which I don't want because I have to provide a link to their site and rely on their connection.  I have also tried to add some Asp.net code from a site but it doesn't work.  My site isn't live yet and that might be the cause?  I need multiple individual counters in multiple divs.  I've tried and am continuing to try learning other languages to accomplish this but I just don't know how to go about making a div view counter.

Comment: Make your own? there are plenty of php view counter tutorials out there. Then simple call it in the div

Comment: ok, thanks.  I have 100 divs on a page.  Just because a user views a page doesn't mean he scrolls down and views the 99th div.  Can a php view counter do this?  In other words, only count when a div is viewed and not when a page is viewed.

Comment: updated my answer, you can use `jQuery` to detect that. I cant give you the exact code for this im afriad, but I can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many `php` hit counter tutorials out there.

Heres one I found doing a google search:

https://code.google.com/p/simphp/

All you would have to do is call:

```
<? include("home/public_html/hits/simphp.php"); ?>
```

Then place this in the div you want counted:

```
<div id="count"><? echo $info; ?></div>
```

To detect if a div is visible in the browser window, use `jQuery`:

[Check if div is viewable in window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114611/check-if-div-is-viewable-in-window)